# scrape multiple pages with python (real estate website)

Tags: python, pagination, scrape

I can't seem to scrape mutiple pages from a real estate website. I only seem to scrape the first page. Any help will be apreciated. The code below is what i gathered so far, i tried various solution in stackoverflow and i can't get it to work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

def nonxt(target):
    if target is not None:
        spl_word = '>'
        sagent = str(target)
        p1 = sagent.split(spl_word, 1)
        p2 = p1[1]
        res = p2.split('<', 1)
        resf = res[0]
        cleanres = resf.strip().replace('\n', '')
        res = cleanres
        return res

def extract(page):
    URL = f'https://www.point2homes.com/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html?LocationGeoId=&LocationGeoAreaId=240589&Location=San%20Felipe,%20Baja%20California,%20Mexico&page={page}'
    headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1"}
    # Here the user agent is for Edge browser on windows 10. You can find your browser user agent from the above given link.
    r = requests.get(url=URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    listing = soup.findAll('article')
    with open('housing.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf8', newline= '') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        header = ['Address', 'Beds', 'Baths', 'Size', 'Area', 'Acres', 'Price', 'Agent', 'Firm']
        thewriter.writerow(header)
        for ls in listing:
            address = ls.find('div', class_="address-container").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            try:
                beds = ls.find('li', class_="ic-beds").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
                beds = ("Data Not Logged")
            try:
                baths = ls.find('li', class_="ic-baths").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
                baths = ("Data not logged")
            try:
                size = ls.find('li', class_="ic-sqft").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
                size = ("Data not logged")
            try:
                acre = ls.find('li', class_="ic-lotsize").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            except:
                acre = ("Data not found")
            area = ls.find('li', class_="property-type ic-proptype").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            price = ls.find('span', class_="green").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
            agentstr = ls.find('div', class_="agent-name")
            agent = ''
            agent1 = nonxt(agentstr)
            firmstr = ls.find('div', class_="agent-company")
            firm = ''
            if firmstr is not None:
              spl_word = '>'
              sagent = str(firmstr)
              p1 = sagent.split(spl_word, 1)
              p2 = p1[1]
              res = p2.split('<', 1)
              resf = res[0]
              cleanres = resf.strip().replace('\n', '')
              firm = cleanres
              r_list =[address, beds, baths, size, area, acre, price, agent1, firm]
              thewriter.writerow(r_list)
        return
page = 1
for i in range(1, 10):
    page = page+1
    webpage = f'https://www.point2homes.com/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html?LocationGeoId=&LocationGeoAreaId=240589&Location=San%20Felipe,%20Baja%20California,%20Mexico&page={page}'
    webpage = webpage + str(page)
    print(f'Getting page {i}...')
    c = extract(webpage)
    transform(c)
```

I can't seem to scrape more than the first page, please help

Comment: "page" is an URL? if not I don't understand why "extract" takes and URL as argument. Also please only manipulate URL with urrlib.parse with functions in that library to properly construct your URL before passing them to requests

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `extract` function takes a `page` which should be the number of the page. However, in `for i in range(1, 10):` you're passing an entire url as the parameter, instead of the page number.

To fix this, simply replace:

```py
page = 1
for i in range(1, 10):
    page = page+1
    webpage = f'https://www.point2homes.com/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html?LocationGeoId=&LocationGeoAreaId=240589&Location=San%20Felipe,%20Baja%20California,%20Mexico&page={page}'
    webpage = webpage + str(page)
    print(f'Getting page {i}...')
    c = extract(webpage)
    transform(c)
```

With:

```py
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(f'Getting page {i}...')
    c = extract(i)
    transform(c)
```

Being an engineer at [WebScrapingAPI](https://www.webscrapingapi.com) myself, I came up with this script which uses concurrent requests to speed up scraping for you:

```py
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import concurrent.futures

API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>'
SCRAPER_URL = 'https://api.webscrapingapi.com/v1'

# Get the total number of pages by collecting the #bottom-list-no-results div and 
# dividing the totla number of results to 24
def get_total_pages():
    url = 'https://www.point2homes.com/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html?LocationGeoId=&LocationGeoAreaId=240589&Location=San%20Felipe,%20Baja%20California,%20Mexico&page=1'
    params = {
        "api_key":API_KEY,
        "url": url,
        "render_js":"1",
        "wait_for_css":"#bottom-list-no-results",
        "extract_rules":'{"pages":{"selector":"#bottom-list-no-results","output":"text"}}',
    }
    res = requests.get(SCRAPER_URL, params=params)
    json_res = json.loads(res.text)
    return round(int(json_res['pages'][0].replace('Results','').partition(' of ')[2])/24)

# Scrape page and return properties
def get_properties_from_page(url):
    params = {
        "api_key":API_KEY,
        "url": url,
        "render_js":"1",
        "wait_for_css":"#bottom-list-no-results",
        "extract_rules":'{"articles":{"selector":"article","output":"html"}}',
    }
    res = requests.get(SCRAPER_URL, params=params)
    json_res = json.loads(res.text)
    return json_res['articles']


# Begin scraping
LISTINGS = []
RESULTS = []
URLS = []

total_pages = get_total_pages()
print(f'[i] Total number of pages: {total_pages}')
for i in range(1, total_pages+1):
    URLS.append(f'https://www.point2homes.com/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html?LocationGeoId=&LocationGeoAreaId=240589&Location=San%20Felipe,%20Baja%20California,%20Mexico&page={i}')

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    res = executor.map(get_properties_from_page, URLS)
    for r in res:
        LISTINGS += r

for listing in LISTINGS:
    ls = BeautifulSoup(listing, 'html.parser')
    address = ls.find('div', class_='address-container').text.replace('\n', "").strip()
    area = ls.find('li', class_="property-type ic-proptype").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
    try:
        beds = ls.find('li', class_="ic-beds").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
    except:
        beds = ("Data Not Logged")
    try:
        baths = ls.find('li', class_="ic-baths").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
    except:
        baths = ("Data not logged")
    try:
        size = ls.find('li', class_="ic-sqft").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
    except:
        size = ("Data not logged")
    try:
        acre = ls.find('li', class_="ic-lotsize").text.replace('\n', "").strip()
    except:
        acre = ("Data not found")
    RESULTS.append({
        "address":address,
        "area":area,
        "beds":beds,
        "baths":baths,
        "size":size,
        "acre":acre
    })

print(RESULTS)
```